# How can I pass the selected value from a drop down list to the controller in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, listbox

How can I pass the selected value from a drop down list to the controller in Ruby?

```
<select>
  <option value="0">New</option>
  <option value="1">SubCategory1</option>
  <option value="2">SubCategory2</option>
  <option value="3">SubCategory3</option>
</select>
```

still i having a problem here is my code

```
  <select name="category_id">
  <option value="0">New Category</option>
  <% for category in categories %>
    <option value="<%= category.id %>"><%= category.name %></option>
  <% end %>
  </select>

 def create
        if params[:category_id] == 0
            @category = Category.new(params[:category])
            respond_to do |format|
            if @category.save
            end

        else
        @subcategory = Subcategory.new(params[:subcategory])
            respond_to do |format|
                if @subcategory.save
                    ....
                end
            end
        end
  end
```

the params[:category_id] == 0 is never executed because is not passing the value 0 to the controller. How i can solve it?

Comment: You can find help on `select` here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 8):

Give a name attribute to the select. Once the form is submitted, you'll find the value of the selected option in the `params` Hash.

For example

```
<select name="category_id">
  <option value="0">New</option>
  <option value="1">SubCategory1</option>
  <option value="2">SubCategory2</option>
  <option value="3">SubCategory3</option>
</select> 

params[:category_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Product model and you want to store the category_id in it. In your form, you would do like this.

```
<select name="product[category_id]">
  <option value="0">New</option>
  <option value="1">SubCategory1</option>
  <option value="2">SubCategory2</option>
  <option value="3">SubCategory3</option>
</select>
```

Then you can get it in controller with `params[:product][:category_id]`

I suggest you use form helper gems like [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). It makes your life much easier.